# using elmah logger with nuget installer and modifying web config

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, elmah

I used prevoius version of elmah in my asp.net mvc application and there I had to modify web config. For example I had to add this lines :

```
<system.webServer>
.....
    <handlers>
          <remove name="MvcHttpHandler" />
          <remove name="UrlRoutingHandler" />
          <add name="Elmah" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
          <add name="MvcHttpHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="*.mvc" type="System.Web.Mvc.MvcHttpHandler, System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
        </handlers>
</system.webServer>

    <system.web>
....
 <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
      <add verb="*" path="*.mvc" validate="false" type="System.Web.Mvc.MvcHttpHandler, System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
    </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
```

But now, with nuget installation, is it necessary to manually modify web.config ?

Comment: When you install through nuget the web.config modifications will be done by itself

Comment: you mean It does not need any extra action ?

Comment: Are you going to use db to store the elmah logs?

Comment: I dont have problem setting elmah for storing its data in sql or some other db, just want to be assure about any problem with httphandler section.